# What is the difference between S/cm and Scm-1?

Tags: electricity

Conductivity is noted in S.cm-1 in this http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja502765n

i wanted to compare it to the conductivity values listed on wikipedia for common materials.

i could not find information on what the difference was through google's broken search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same. $a^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$